Explain the output for "ls -ltr *s*" in ubuntu 22.04
I am new to Ubuntu and was trying to write some commands on my own. I found that ls -ltr * is a wild card, using ls -ltr *.txt will show all files having extension of .txt. Whereas, ls -ltr ex* will show all files with starting with file name as ex.
When I tried to run, ls -ltr *s*, it shows the following output:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 knn   72 May  7 16:27 lst.txt

Videos:
total 0

Templates:
total 0

snap:
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 knn 4096 May  3 10:44 snap-store 
drwxr-xr-x 5 knn 4096 May  3 12:00 firefox
drwxr-xr-x 5 knn 4096 May  3 12:00 snapd-desktop-integration
drwxr-xr-x 4 knn 4096 May  5 00:40 vlc
drwxr-xr-x 4 knn 4096 May  7 10:45 code

Pictures:
total 0

Music:
total 0

Downloads:
total 10666304
-rw-rw-r-- 1 knn  107002536 Apr 30 05:38  google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 knn  107002536 May  3 10:45 'google-chrome-stable_current_amd64(1).deb'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 knn   10888357 May  3 13:21  Non_Isomorphic.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 knn 1652702742 May  4 15:38  Kung.Fu.Panda.4.2024.1080p.10bit.WEB-DL.Hindi.English.ESubs.MoviesMod.org.mkv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 knn 2866374921 May  5 01:00 'The Kerala Story (2023) {Hindi-Malayalam-Tamil-Telugu} 1080p WEB-DL .mkv'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 knn 2694044153 May  5 01:25  Jack.Reacher.Never.Go.Back.2016.Bluray.1080P.Hindi.Eng.Msubs.MoviesMod.org.mkv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 knn 3011257260 May  5 01:26  Jack.Reacher.2012.1080p.Bluray.Hindi.English.Msubs.MoviesMod.org.mkv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 knn  472983266 May  7 11:07  Fukrey.3.2023.480p.WEB-DL.ESub.x264-TopMovies.dev.mkv

Documents:
total 0

Desktop:
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 knn 4096 May  5 11:48 BS
drwxrwxr-x 3 knn 4096 May  7 14:09 Python_practice


Hint: run echo ls -ltr *s*

Welcome to Unix&Linux SE. ls (1) lists files and directories, if that is the question (please update your question so it is actually in the form of a question). Also note that in Unix-like OSes the ending of files isn't treated specially, unlike in DOS (there are no "extensions"). A file can be named some.random.notes, for example.

When using ls with globs, you generally want -d and --: ls -lrtd -- *s*.

I take it that you are trying to list all files and directories in your current directory whose names have the letter s in them.
You need to add -d to your options to list directories but not their contents.
Also to guard against the possibility that one of the names might start with - (and be misinterpreted as a command option) you need to add -- which declares the end of options list.
So you command should be:
$ ls -ltrd -- *s*

